# Can Xero contacts be filtered (by name) case insensitive?

Tags: filter, contacts, xero-api

Using the `Where` filter with `Contacts`, is it possible to make the term `Name.Contains("Peter")` not case sensitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ToLower()` to achieve this - make your where clause something like:

```
Name.ToLower().Contains("peter")
```

Comment: Took me a while, but I also found `ToLower()` - shame the API docs don't tell us more about the available methods.

Thanks!